Prove that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open iff $A \cap \overline{X} \subset \overline{A \cap X}$, for all $X \subset \mathbb{R}$
I managed to prove the converse, but I am stuck trying to prove that A is open given that the inclusion holds. I have tried by definition without any results, and reasoning by contradiction just makes it harder. Any help is highly appreciated.

Hint: You can prove directly that $A$ is open by applying your inclusion to $X = A^c$. Can you take it from here?
